# Вхождение подстроки в строку на определенное количество символов

Tags: javascript, строки, lodash

Мне нужно определить, входит ли строка B в строку A на определенное количество символов. В моем случае, это 6 символов:

Например,

```
строка А: 3897856787
строка B: 7856787
```

Если строка B входит в строку А, должно вернуть true, иначе - false.

Если,

```
строка А: 3897856787
строка B: 87
```

В таком случае должно вернуть false, тк вхождение всего 2 символов.

Пробовал метод includes из lodash, но он возвращает true, даже при вхождении 2 цифр.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение!

Comment: а вариант проверять строку B через `if` не подходит?

Comment: напишите вопрос более развернуто...у меня сложилось впечатление что его можно решить простым `str.indexOf("подстрока")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const isMatch = (str, match) => (( str.length > 5 ) ? match.indexOf(str) > -1 : false);

const match = '123456789'; // Строка A
const a = '123'; // Строка B
const b = '345678'; // Строка C

console.log(isMatch(a, match)) // false Строка A не содержит строку B
console.log(isMatch(b, match)) // true Строка A содержит строку С

// Кастом для внятности
console.log(isMatch('112233', '0011223344')) // true
```

Comment: Подскажи, а как в данной функции, проверять последние 5 цифр на вхождение?